# How to SortBy two parameters in OCL?

Tags: sorting, ocl

I need to sort the collection of Persons by two parameters, by Surnames and after by Names. How can I do something like this in OCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sortedBy` function sorts elements using a the criteria expressed in its body and a `<` relationship between each gathered result.

In your case, assuming that you have a `surname` attribute, the following statement will sort the collection `c` using the `<` operator on each surname gathered (so a `<` on strings):

```
c->sortedBy(p | p.surname)
```

An idea could be to compute a unique string using the surname and the name concatenated toghether. Thus, if you have:

- George Smith
- Garry Smith
- George Smath

The comparison would be done between "Smith_George", "Smith_Garry" and "Smath_George" and would be ordered, following the lexicographical order, to:

1. George Smath (Sm**a**th_George)
2. Garry Smith (Smith_G**a**rry)
3. George Smith (smith_G**e**orge)

Finally, the OCL request would be (assuming `surname` and `name` as existing attributes):

```
c->sortedBy(p | p.surname + '_' + p.name)
```

This little trick does the job, but it is not "exactly" a two parameters comparison for sortedBy.

Comment: It seems to me that this solution won't work in all cases, I need something universal. This solution will be wrong in case if we have for example two dates. For example, the date when the project was started and the date when the project was finished. What can I use in such cases?

Comment: As I said, this solution worked in your specific case using name/surname is it will uses lexicographical order. I'm not sure, but I don't think that OCL sortedBy function is able to perform this two criteria search. In other cases, another trick should be found, in your start/end date example, you could compute the time spent by each project using the end/start date and  sort them using this criteria. Otherwise, translating date in a yyy-mm-dd format (with signficative 0 obvioulsy), the string trick with the lexicographical order should work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you inspired me. I just raised http://issues.omg.org/browse/OCL25-213 whose text is:

The sortedBy iteration provides an elegant solution to a sort problem in which the sort metric is a projection of the sorted object. Thus sortedBy(p|p.name) or just sortedBy(name) is short and avoids the opportunities for typos from a more conventional exposition involving comparison of two objects. The natural solution may well be an efficient one for large collections with non-trivial metrics.

However the sortedBy solution is unfamiliar and so confusing for newcomers and unsuitable for multi-key sorting for which an artificial compound single key may need to be constructed.

One solution might be to provide a more conventional iterator such as sort(p1, p2 | comparison-expression) allowing a two key sort:

sort(p1, p2 | let diff1 = p1.key1.compareTo(p2.key1) in
if diff1 <> 0 the diff 1 else p1.key2.compareTo(p2.key2) endif)

However this has poor readability and ample opportunities for typos.

Alternatively sortedBy with a Tuple-valued metric might support multiple keys as:

sortedBy(Tuple{first=key1,second=key2})

(The alphabetical order of the Tuple part names determines the priority.)

(Since sortedBy is declaratively clear and compact, inefficient small/trivial implementations can be optimized to their sort() equivalents.)

Comment: _sortedBy with a Tuple-valued metric..._

Can you kindly provide a reference for the definition of the `<` operation on Tuple in OCL 2.4? As far as my understanding goes, the `<` operation is only defined for Real, String, and UnlimitedNatural types. However, sortedBy in sub clause 11.9 requires that "the type of the body expression must have the `<` operation defined."

Comment: Yes (and no). In principle, a user is free to use Complete OCL to add a < operation to any type; whether that includes a built-in such as Boolean is debateable. Eclipse OCL generalizes to any type whose underlying Java class has a compareTo operation which is kind of handy for e.g. EDate. The specific semantics of a Tuple-based sort operation/iteration could be defined as a part-wise and of types that must be comparable.

Answer (score 0):

The OCL sortedBy(lambda) appears to be very different to Java's sort(comparator) apparently requiring a projection of the objects as the metric for sorting. However if the projection is self, you have a different Java functionality. Therefore if you do sortedBy(p | p) the sorting is dependent on the < operation for p.

To facilitate this, the Eclipse OCL prototype of a future OCL introduces an OclComparable type with a compareTo method enabling all relational operations to be realized provided your custom type extends the OclComparable type.

(A similar OclSummable with zero() and sum() operates supports Collection::sum() generically; e.g. String realizes sum as a concatenation.)